# При использовании MDL блоки находятся друг под другом, а не сбоку

Tags: html, css, material-design

Почему 3-ий блок находится под 2-ым?

Как сделать что бы 3-ий блок находился с правой стороны от 2-го (рядом со вторым)?

```
<div class="content-grid mdl-grid">
    <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
        <header class="mdl-layout__header">
            <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
                <span class="mdl-layout-title">Leniva</span>
                <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
                <nav class="mdl-navigation">
                    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="bemmdl.html">Home</a>
                    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="bemmdl2.html">Blog</a>
                    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="bemmdl3.html">About</a>
                    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="bemmdl4.html">Contact</a>
                </nav>
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--expandable">
                    <label class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon" for="search-expandable">
                        <i class="material-icons">search</i>
                    </label>
                    <div class="mdl-textfield__expandable-holder">
                        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="search-expandable" />
                        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="search-expandable">Search text</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
            <span class="mdl-layout-title">Leniva</span>
            <nav class="mdl-navigation">
                <a href="#" class="mdl-navigation__link">Products</a>
                <a href="#" class="mdl-navigation__link">Services</a>
                <a href="#" class="mdl-navigation__link">Portfolios</a>
                <a href="#" class="mdl-navigation__link">Achievements</a>
                <a href="#" class="mdl-navigation__link">Blog</a>
            </nav>
        </div>


        <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-cell--8-col-tablet mdl-cell--4-col-phone">
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor.</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error vitae, a aliquam reiciendis laborum voluptatibus sunt deleniti, omnis assumenda vero nostrum unde soluta quidem ut necessitatibus labore quasi fugiat earum voluptatum. Laudantium ex quas impedit voluptate minima officiis, perspiciatis aperiam aliquid, molestiae, cumque consequuntur dolor quibusdam molestias quam. Nihil, aspernatur cumque accusamus, delectus saepe reprehenderit. Nemo adipisci, sequi amet natus iste laudantium quia saepe dolores ratione, aut ab voluptatum facere enim deleniti blanditiis molestiae consectetur cum, earum laborum. Nam recusandae voluptas repellat iusto perferendis aut placeat pariatur consequuntur harum deleniti, blanditiis debitis eveniet aliquam! Deserunt aliquam, in doloribus placeat totam pariatur suscipit repudiandae ullam reprehenderit voluptates explicabo, quas neque incidunt ex, cumque tenetur iste mollitia esse! Praesentium tempore autem aspernatur consequatur iure blanditiis aliquam suscipit recusandae, consequuntur ea voluptatibus sequi, fuga voluptatum eius quam atque facilis, laudantium, assumenda dolorem animi! Commodi beatae sapiente consectetur, deserunt voluptatibus saepe veniam harum dolorum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-cell--2-col-phone">
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt fugit vel nam quisquam dolores non aliquam reiciendis, consequuntur voluptas, explicabo corrupti atque iure aspernatur eos soluta repudiandae dolorem eveniet maiores pariatur, dicta debitis accusamus. Veritatis porro ipsa fugit enim consequuntur cum non blanditiis sequi error. Iste expedita repellat praesentium magnam autem sapiente facilis officiis nisi deserunt officia! Distinctio, natus voluptates odit laudantium, dolore fugit animi libero, accusantium aperiam commodi et. Quam voluptas neque dolorum quis! Iste, ipsum pariatur asperiores illum fuga accusantium laborum unde nihil corporis, odit ullam rem. Adipisci ex recusandae tenetur autem iure, quas accusamus ullam aspernatur sapiente.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-cell--2-col-phone">
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum eveniet aliquid labore adipisci ab dolorum esse amet, iste molestias quod quam corporis voluptate quo commodi autem iusto! Dignissimos voluptatibus beatae, dolorum facere voluptates rerum iste voluptatem, assumenda doloremque voluptate deleniti optio! Molestias nobis vel molestiae eveniet quibusdam. Dolores quaerat, ducimus itaque similique assumenda ratione aliquam dolor voluptatem eius ipsam nulla labore eum commodi, illo at hic aperiam adipisci animi. Aliquid dolores, voluptatibus natus ipsam expedita eligendi quis mollitia ut delectus beatae ducimus aspernatur. Voluptatum explicabo nemo numquam est, quisquam aliquid quasi officiis ullam unde sint vel accusamus nihil dolor, labore.</p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: почитай свой вопрос со стороны обычных пользователей, которые хотят тебе помочь и дай ответ, получилось? Вот, что ты написал...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что нужно почитать [документацию по данному фреймворку](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#layout-section/grid)!!!

Ячейки сетки `mdl-cell` нужно оборачивать в `mdl-grid`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/material.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="content-grid">
    <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
        <header class="mdl-layout__header">
            <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
                <span class="mdl-layout-title">Leniva</span>
                <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
                <nav class="mdl-navigation">
                    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="bemmdl.html">Home</a>
                    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="bemmdl2.html">Blog</a>
                    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="bemmdl3.html">About</a>
                    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="bemmdl4.html">Contact</a>
                </nav>
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--expandable">
                    <label class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon" for="search-expandable">
                        <i class="material-icons">search</i>
                    </label>
                    <div class="mdl-textfield__expandable-holder">
                        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="search-expandable" />
                        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="search-expandable">Search text</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
            <span class="mdl-layout-title">Leniva</span>
            <nav class="mdl-navigation">
                <a href="#" class="mdl-navigation__link">Products</a>
                <a href="#" class="mdl-navigation__link">Services</a>
                <a href="#" class="mdl-navigation__link">Portfolios</a>
                <a href="#" class="mdl-navigation__link">Achievements</a>
                <a href="#" class="mdl-navigation__link">Blog</a>
            </nav>
        </div>

      <div class="mdl-layout__content">
        <div class="mdl-grid">
          <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-cell--8-col-tablet mdl-cell--4-col-phone">
              <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor.</h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error vitae, a aliquam reiciendis laborum voluptatibus sunt deleniti, omnis assumenda vero nostrum unde soluta quidem ut necessitatibus labore quasi fugiat earum voluptatum. Laudantium ex quas impedit voluptate minima officiis, perspiciatis aperiam aliquid, molestiae, cumque consequuntur dolor quibusdam molestias quam. Nihil, aspernatur cumque accusamus, delectus saepe reprehenderit. Nemo adipisci, sequi amet natus iste laudantium quia saepe dolores ratione, aut ab voluptatum facere enim deleniti blanditiis molestiae consectetur cum, earum laborum. Nam recusandae voluptas repellat iusto perferendis aut placeat pariatur consequuntur harum deleniti, blanditiis debitis eveniet aliquam! Deserunt aliquam, in doloribus placeat totam pariatur suscipit repudiandae ullam reprehenderit voluptates explicabo, quas neque incidunt ex, cumque tenetur iste mollitia esse! Praesentium tempore autem aspernatur consequatur iure blanditiis aliquam suscipit recusandae, consequuntur ea voluptatibus sequi, fuga voluptatum eius quam atque facilis, laudantium, assumenda dolorem animi! Commodi beatae sapiente consectetur, deserunt voluptatibus saepe veniam harum dolorum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-grid">
          <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-cell--2-col-phone">
              <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt fugit vel nam quisquam dolores non aliquam reiciendis, consequuntur voluptas, explicabo corrupti atque iure aspernatur eos soluta repudiandae dolorem eveniet maiores pariatur, dicta debitis accusamus. Veritatis porro ipsa fugit enim consequuntur cum non blanditiis sequi error. Iste expedita repellat praesentium magnam autem sapiente facilis officiis nisi deserunt officia! Distinctio, natus voluptates odit laudantium, dolore fugit animi libero, accusantium aperiam commodi et. Quam voluptas neque dolorum quis! Iste, ipsum pariatur asperiores illum fuga accusantium laborum unde nihil corporis, odit ullam rem. Adipisci ex recusandae tenetur autem iure, quas accusamus ullam aspernatur sapiente.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-cell--2-col-phone">
              <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum eveniet aliquid labore adipisci ab dolorum esse amet, iste molestias quod quam corporis voluptate quo commodi autem iusto! Dignissimos voluptatibus beatae, dolorum facere voluptates rerum iste voluptatem, assumenda doloremque voluptate deleniti optio! Molestias nobis vel molestiae eveniet quibusdam. Dolores quaerat, ducimus itaque similique assumenda ratione aliquam dolor voluptatem eius ipsam nulla labore eum commodi, illo at hic aperiam adipisci animi. Aliquid dolores, voluptatibus natus ipsam expedita eligendi quis mollitia ut delectus beatae ducimus aspernatur. Voluptatum explicabo nemo numquam est, quisquam aliquid quasi officiis ullam unde sint vel accusamus nihil dolor, labore.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Так и должно быть что появилась вторая полоса прокрутки? Так же почему вертикальные margin между блоками не схлопываются?

Comment: @DmitriiLenivec, исправила и этот бок. Смотрите ответ!

Comment: Спасибо, не сразу заметил что вы убрали mdl-grid из обёртки.